# Árbol de dependencia a partir de la matriz de adyacencia

Tags: r

A partir de una matriz de adyacencia:

```
        r01-r07 r03 r04 r05 r06 r08-r02 r09 r10 I1 I2 I3 I4
r01-r07       0   0   0   1   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r03           1   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r04           1   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r05           0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r06           0   1   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r08-r02       0   1   0   0   0       0   1   0  0  0  0  0
r09           0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
r10           0   0   0   1   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
I1            1   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
I2            0   0   1   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
I3            0   0   0   0   0       1   0   0  0  0  0  0
I4            0   0   0   0   0       0   1   0  0  0  0  0
```

¿Es posible obtener una estructura que refleje el nivel en el que se encuentra el objeto? Tal que 1 significa que se encuentra en el nivel y 0 lo contrario, tal que:

```
       r01-r07 r03 r04 r05 r06 r08-r02 r09 r10 I1 I2 I3 I4
root         0   0   0   0   1       0   0   1  1  1  1  1
level1       0   0   1   0   0       1   0   0  0  0  0  0
level2       0   1   0   0   0       0   1   0  0  0  0  0
level3       1   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
level4       0   0   0   1   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
```

[image: The drawn model]

Estoy usando los métodos `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` and `get.adjedgelist(network, mode = "out")` para la obtención de los ejes del paquete igraph.

Puedo obtener el orden, pero no los niveles con `topo_sort(network, mode = "out")`

```
+ 12/12 vertices, named, from c00e2ba:
 [1] r06     r10     I1      I2      I3      I4      r04     r08-r02 r03     r09     r01-r07 r05
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
library(igraph)
# Matriz de adyacencia
x <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0), ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(x) <- c("r01-r07", "r03", "r04", "r05", "r06", "r08-r02",
                 "r09", "r10", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4")
row.names(x) <- c("r01-r07", "r03", "r04", "r05", "r06", "r08-r02",
                 "r09", "r10", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4")

# Creación de la red
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(x), mode = "directed")
# Lista de ejes
print(get.adjedgelist(network,mode = "out"))
# Nodos ordenados
print(topo_sort(network, mode = "out"))
# Visualización
plot.igraph(network, vertex.size = 15, edge.arrow.size = 0.5, vertex.label.dist=3,
   layout=layout.kamada.kawai, vertex.label.color="blue", edge.color="black")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de la función `distances()` generamos una matriz de las distancias mas cortas entre cada par de nodos. Buscando luego, el valor máximo por columna llegamos al nivel de cada nodo:

```
d <- distances(network, mode = "out")
d[is.infinite(d)] <- 0
levels <- apply(d, MARGIN=2, max)
levels

r01-r07     r03     r04     r05     r06 r08-r02     r09     r10      I1      I2      I3      I4 
      3       2       1       4       0       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
```

A partir de este vector es bastante sencillo generar la matriz que buscas

```
l <- lapply(0:max(levels), function(x) as.numeric(levels == x))
m <- matrix(unlist(l), ncol = length(levels), byrow = TRUE)
colnames(m) <- names(levels)
m

     r01-r07 r03 r04 r05 r06 r08-r02 r09 r10 I1 I2 I3 I4
[1,]       0   0   0   0   1       0   0   1  1  1  1  1
[2,]       0   0   1   0   0       1   0   0  0  0  0  0
[3,]       0   1   0   0   0       0   1   0  0  0  0  0
[4,]       1   0   0   0   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
[5,]       0   0   0   1   0       0   0   0  0  0  0  0
```